# Why does this Polynomial have two valid factored forms?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

When factoring $3 + 4a - 7a^2$ why are there two possible factors? $(-7a -3)(a - 1)$ and $(3 + 7a)(1 - a)$. What is the principle? I assume that the two factors are inverse in some way.

Comment: You can always multiply and divide by a unit (an invertible element).  Here you just multiplied each term by $-1$ (noting that $\frac 1{-1}=-1$).

Comment: If you don't require integer coefficients then you could also get, e.g., $(6+14a)(\frac 12-\frac a2)$ and so on.

Comment: Similarly $6 = 2 \times 3$ but also $6 = -2 \times -3$.  This is not regarded as a violation of unique factorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(-7a -3) and (3 + 7a) are "equivalent" in the sense that they differ by a multiplicative constant (which is -1 in this case). The same is true for (a - 1) and (1 - a).

Other instance is: Ax + By + C = 0 and - Ax - By - C = 0 are two different equations but they represent the same straight line.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the two is one is multiplied by -1. If you were to find the solution for `a`. You get `a= -3/7` for both.

Ex 1.

-7a-3 = 0

a = -3/7

Ex 2.

3+7a=0
a = -3/7